# How to change number format for all users?(Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, regional-settings

How can I change number format to be "." instead of "," for all users of my PC in WIndows 10?

Comment: Have you looked in “Control Panel” → “Region and Language” (or whatever it’s called in Windows 10)?

Comment: Yes it changes it only to one user(the current user), not for all the user.

Comment: OK, you’re new here, so I guess you don’t know that we expect question-askers to describe what they have tried and what results they got.  I encourage to take the [tour]; ideally, once on each site where you have an account (i.e., here and [SO]).

Comment: For the voters to close this post : This question is perfectly clear, so no reason to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the **current user and all future users** that will be added, it is enough to
change the setting in *Control Panel → Region → Additional settings*,
change *Decimal symbol*, and click OK.

For **existing user profiles**, if there are too many to manually repeat this
operation for each one, you could set up a Login script that does the
operation.

Create a registry `.reg` file with the required registry changes,
say that it is named `changedecimal.reg` and contains :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International]
"sDecimal"="."
```

Then do the following :

- In the Windows Start menu, enter *Edit group policy*
- In the Local Group Policy Editor, navigate to
  *User Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts*.
- Double-click *Logon*
- Click *Add...*
- Click *Browse...*
- Navigate to and click on `changedecimal.reg`, then on Open
- Click OK.

From now on, the decimal separator will be reset to `.` for every user
when he does logon.
You will need to use an administrator logon account to effect this change.

Comment: If you are in a domain, the domain administrator may be able to do a similar change with Group Policy Management or logon scripts for all users on all PCs.  I haven't tried it specifically.